# VB MVC equivilant of C# OrderBy

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller

I searched up and down but I cannot find how to do this sort in VB

Here is the C# code:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View(db.Categories.Orderby(c => c.Name).ToList();
End Function
```

Comment: https://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/ordering/OrderBy-numbers-lambda-vb

Comment: That's a weird hybrid. `OrderBy()` in VB.net is the same thing, except the `Function()`: `.Orderby(Function(c) c.Name).ToList()`

Comment: Thats not even C# and that code will not even compile... Also it looks like you want to return a view, that will not work as you are trying to return a list. You need to select one item...

Comment: Basically, you're asking how to write a Lambda expression in VB and that is something that you should have looked up for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Return View(db.Categories.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name).ToList());`

The "c => c.Name" is a C# lambda expression, so I've put the corresponding lambda expression in VB.Net.